# PPrint not working (Python)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pprint

I'm trying to use Python's `pprint` on a dictionary but for some reason it isn't working. Here's my code (I'm using PyCharm Pro as my IDE):`

```
from pprint import pprint
message = "Come on Eileen!"
count = {}

for character in message:
    count.setdefault(character, 0)
    count[character] += 1

pprint(count)
```

And here's my output:

```
{' ': 2, '!': 1, 'C': 1, 'E': 1, 'e': 3, 'i': 1, 'l': 1, 'm': 1, 'n': 2, 'o': 2}
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think it is not working? What did you expect instead? That's the correct output for `pprint()`; the output fits on one line.

Comment: I'm reading through Automate the Boring Stuff with Python, in chapter 5 it talks about pprint, gives an example of code (almost identical to mine) but shows to output to be key-pair values being printed on separate lines. *(I just realised the reason it wasn't doing that was because my string wasn't long enough)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The output is entirely correct and expected. From the [`pprint` module documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html):

> The formatted representation **keeps objects on a single line if it can**, and breaks them onto multiple lines if they don’t fit within the allowed width.

Bold emphasis mine.

You could set the `width` keyword argument to `1` to force every key-value pair being printed on a separate line:

```
>>> pprint(count, width=1)
{' ': 2,
 '!': 1,
 'C': 1,
 'E': 1,
 'e': 3,
 'i': 1,
 'l': 1,
 'm': 1,
 'n': 2,
 'o': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to specify the second parameter i.e

```
pprint.pprint(count, width=1)
```

Or in your case

```
pprint(count, width=1)
```

Output:

```
{' ': 2,
 '!': 1,
 'C': 1,
 'E': 1,
 'e': 3,
 'i': 1,
 'l': 1,
 'm': 1,
 'n': 2,
 'o': 2}
```

Answer (score -3):

I am having the same issue when practicing, then I realized I am running the old characterCount.py again and again instead of running the new pretty character Count.py file.
Try to click the run button on the top and choose the right file and run again.